# mybatis avoid generating model class *WithBLOBs

Tags: jpa, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I have to change a column from **varchar2** to **clob**. After generation mybatis creates a *WithBlobs class with fields that extends the original class. To avoid several impacts it would be possible to avoid the creation of the *WithBlobs class ?

Is there a configuration in MyBatis GeneratorXML Configuration File Reference that allows this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default model type to "flat" in your configuration. With that setting, only a single model class will be generated that contains all fields.

```xml
<generatorConfiguration>
  <context defaultModelType="flat">
    ...
  <context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```